# How many characters can an IP address be?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address

I have to create a field in a mysql table to store ip addresses. I need to know the maximum characters an ip address can possibly be. Whether ipv4, ipv6 or some other type that can render a valid ip address unusually long. So what should I set the character limit to?

I am asking for length in the sense that the word "foo" has 3 characters, not in terms of bytes or anything like that.

Comment: Please move to stackoverflow.com: it is a programming question

Comment: Here is an answer showing the IPv6 address can be up to 45 characters long: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076714/max-length-for-client-ip-address#answer-7477384

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An IPv6 address, at its longest, would be 8 sets of 4 characters (32 total), each set separated by a colon. That makes 39 characters.

An IPv4 address is at most 4 sets of 3 numbers (12 characters), each set separated by a dot (.). That makes 15 characters.

All of this assumes the IP addresses should be stored in human-readable form. I prefer to store IP addresses in decimal form, as you never quite know how it will be used. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks a lot, human readable form is fine for my use case as I am never going to use them generally. I am only storing the ips of people who signup on my site in case they ever upload anything seriously offending and I have to hand over their info to authorities.

Comment: Sorry for the necropost, but actually an IPv6 can be up to 45 characters long in some cases of IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses, since it is prefixed with `:<ipv4 original address>`

Comment: @axelduch *suffixed

Answer (score 2):

This is not as easy as one might think.

In most cases your are safe with **45**.

**Normal IPv6 address**

```
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000
```

> 8 * 4 + 7 = **39**

---

**IPv4-mapped IPv6 address**

See [rfc4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.5.2)

```
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:192.168.100.228
```

> (6 * 4 + 5) + 1 + (4 * 3 + 3) = 29 + 1 + 15 = **45**

---

[Header files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166132/maximum-length-of-the-textual-representation-of-an-ipv6-address#comment2055398_166157) define INET6_ADDRSTRLEN to be **46**

---

**IPv6 with scope zone**

See [rfc4007](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4007#section-11)

Scope zone can be a number or even a string (interface name).

```
ff02::5678%5
ff08::9abc%interface10
```

The length of the interface name depends on the system. In Linux it is defined by the IFNAMSIZ constant. 16 is a common value. With the 45 chars from above:

> 45 + 1 + 16 = **62**

---

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166132/maximum-length-of-the-textual-representation-of-an-ipv6-address